# 500 internal server error when execute a simple PHP loop program?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

```
<?php
set_time_limit(600);
while (1){
usleep(30000000);
}
?>
```

The php program above causing the 500 internal server error. The problem is , I have set the time limit as 600 -> 10 minutes. And I am expecting it will run for ten minutes, for 30 second each , it will run a while loop for 1 time, and keep the activity to 10 minute. However, it return 500 internal server error  at round 2 minutes. What is the root cause / how to fix the problem ? thanks

Comment: is it causes by high memory consumption? thanks

Comment: Can you check error log?

Comment: There's probably more than just PHP's execution time limit between your browser and PHP.

Comment: I am using IIS server, it logs only test.php status 500.. or are there any error log in php?

Comment: amazon free web hosting service

Comment: what is the reason to have so much time for executing? There is no time limit when using CLI (console, not browser), so you can use console php command like `php -f index.php` and execute it forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spun your code up on my own Linux-based web-server. I used a Linux server rather than IIS simply because I thought it would give me more debugging information.
Your code for me works just fine. It doesn't time out. I would then have to say that there is something specific to IIS. I would check the Event Log. A 500 error should have something interesting in there. To get to the event log (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524984(v=vs.90).aspx):

- From the Start menu, click Run. In the Open box, type `eventvwr`. Click OK.
- Event Viewer is listed under the System Tools node.

I would suggest, if you need this program to wait for 10 minutes, either go into your PHP.ini file (if that's the problem) and up the max_execution_time by A LOT, or as an alternative, let the page sit for 10 seconds and then reload the same page with `header()`. The advantage to this approach is that you aren't killing EXTRA CPU cycles by just spinning and locking everything up. You are instead just re-querying your server and using a persistent cookie:

```
<?php
echo "Time Slept: ".$_COOKIE['total_time_slept']; //persistent variable you can use to measure how much time has elapsed
if($_COOKIE['total_time_slept'] < 1000) //if less than 10 minutes
{     
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $sec = 10;        
    setcookie('total_time_slept', $_COOKIE['total_time_slept']+$sec); //append that time to the counter
    header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page"); //reload this page every 10 seconds
}
?>
```

Comment: From my insepction , sleep should be the root problem , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with **usleep** on a LAMP installation where PHP run in **safe-mode**.

So my suggestion is check if your PHP run on **safe-mode**. If that's the case try using the **sleep** function (although it won't help if you want to loop each 0.001s for instance).

Note also that **usleep** doesn't work on PHP Windows platforms until PHP 5.

I know this thread is old but I hope this check will help the others.